# yii2 pass variable to another model

Tags: php, model-view-controller, yii, yii2, upload

is it possible to do something like this?

model:

```
class Model1 extends ActiveRecord {

    public $contentUploadedFile;
    ...

    public function extract() {
        ... (assign values from uploaded file content to Model attributes, e.g:)
        $this->datum = $contentUploadedFile[1];
        ...
    }
}
```

upload model:

```
class UploadModel extends Model {

    public $uploadedFiles;

    public function rules() {
        return [
            [['uploadedFiles'], 'file', 'extensions' => 'txt', 'checkExtensionByMimeType' => false, 'skipOnEmpty' => true, 'maxFiles' => 2],
        ];
    }
}
```

upload controller:

```
    class UploadController extends Controller {
    ...

    public function actionUpload() {
        $model = new UploadModel;

        if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->validate()) {
            $files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'uploadedFiles');

            foreach ($files as $file) {
                $t = new Model1;
                $t->contentUploadedFile = file($file->tempName);

                $t->extract();
                $t->save();
            }
        }

        return $this->render('upload', [
                    'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work (undefined variable contentUploadedFile). Maybe my logic is totally wrong. All in all, is it possible to pass value to another model somehow similar like this? Or is it totally wrong logic? It would be nice if there would be a builtin functionality in Yii2 that would handle multiple created models, but not using a form and still, with proper validation. Is there something like this?
Thanks.

Comment: What mean doesn't work.  error? ...not save in db? .. save wrong data?

Comment: undefined variable contentUploadedFile

Comment: I have update the answer .. i think you  missing $this accessing contentUploadedFile ... $this->contentUploadedFile..

Comment: Yeah, I have seen it only after I've figured it out myself also :) but of course your initial idea led me to that so thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a first step this way

```
class UploadController extends Controller {
...

  public function actionUpload() {
      $model = new UploadModel;

      if (Yii::$app->request->isPost && $model->validate()) {
          $files = UploadedFile::getInstances($model, 'uploadedFiles');

          foreach ($files as $file) {
              $t = new Model1;
              $t->contentUploadedFile = file($file->tempName);
              // first try local assigment when all work transfer the logic in the model extract() function
              $t->dbfield1 =  $t->contentUploadedFile->field1
              $t->dbfield2 =  $t->contentUploadedFile->field2              
              // $t->extract();
              // 
              if ($t->validate()) {
                $t->save();
              } else {
              // validation failed: $errors is an array containing error messages
                $errors = $t->errors;
                var_dump($errors);
              }

              if 
          }
      }

      return $this->render('upload', [
                  'model' => $model,
      ]);
  }
}
```

For model use $this to refer the attribute

```
class Model1 extends ActiveRecord {

   public $contentUploadedFile;
   ...

   public function extract() {
       ... (assign values from uploaded file content to Model attributes, e.g:)
        $this->datum = $this->$contentUploadedFile[1];
        ...
   }
}
```

Comment: first try, local assignment works. then changed this in Model1: `$this->datum = $this->contentUploadedFile[1];` and it basically works (so many thanks for that), but I get no `var_dump($errors);` and I can upload only 1 of the two files. How can I make `var_dump($errors);` visible?

Comment: there are 2 files I'm trying to upload, and only one is successful. but I don't see the error message, why is the second not validating. can you please help me with this? And also would be nice to know how to make it work only then insert all into db when all validates. If any of them fails, none to insert.

Comment: Check if the foreach is executed two time or only one.. is strange the code don't var_dump($errors); and why you use new Model1 instead of Model1(); try se the ()

Comment: I've opened this question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34969355/yii2-upload-create-multiple-models-only-if-all-validates). As I see, the `()` makes no difference. If I make it `die;` however, I see the `var_dump($errors);` but it's not really nice :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101531/discussion-between-user2511599-and-scaisedge).